# How is the time complexity of building k-d tree O(nlog^2n) when O(nlog(n)) median search is used?

Tags: machine-learning, knn, kdtree

The time complexity of building a k-d tree using O(nlogn) meidan search is given as O(nlog^2n) in [wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/K-d_tree). Can anybody explain how it is O(nlog^2n)?

Answer (score 3):

When constructing a kdtree with a median search you get a [balanced binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Construction). A balanced binary tree has [height O(log(n))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Properties_of_binary_trees). You search for the median(s) at every layer of this tree when constructing it. So if this search takes O(n * log(n)), you get: log(n) * n * log(n) = n * log(n)^2.